# How to access an object outside of a multiprocessing process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

here is my code

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
a = []
def f(x):
    a.append(x*x)
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))


print(a)
```

I would expect `print(a)` to output `[1,4,9]`. However, it just outputs an empty array. Is there a way to easily fix this, ideally allowing `f()` to access `a`?

Comment: Multiple processes *do not share state* because they are *seperate python processes*. There are various approaches to sharing state, none of which are straight forward. Ideally, multiprocessing code should be designed to not need it, but [check out the docs for some options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Comment: The `print` of `p.map` has the answer anyway.  Just delete `a = []`, `a.append(x*x)`, and `print(a)`.  `Pool` collects the results.